# I'm making an app involving saving data to a textfield and loading it back. It's working in the simulator but not in on my actual iPhone. Why so?

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocoa, ios-simulator, saving-data

In the program I use this method to create a file in which I can save:

```
-(NSString*) saveFilePath{
NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
                  [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],
                  @"savingfile.plist"];
return path;}
```

Then I used a button to initiate the process of putting the data into the file (I first put it all into an array so that it would be easier.):

```
- (IBAction)save
{

NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[myArray addObject:name.text];
[myArray addObject:position.text];
[myArray addObject:cell.text];
[myArray addObject:office.text];
[myArray addObject:company.text];
[myArray writeToFile:[self saveFilePath] atomically:YES];

}
```

Finally, I loaded the information back into the textfields in the - (void)viewDidAppear method.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
NSMutableArray* myArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self saveFilePath]];
name.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:0];
position.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:1];
cell.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:2];
office.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:3];
company.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:4];
}
```

For some reason, on the simulator it's working perfectly on the simulator, but not working at all when I try to run on my physical iPhone.

Comment: Did you mean to post the same function twice?

Comment: One difference between simulator and device is that the code running on the device "is case sensitive" simpler put. But we will have to see the load method too , you posted the same method twice.

Comment: no @DanF I didn't mean to post the same method twice.  I realized that and edited it as soon as I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think  you're trying to save to a location that's read-only on iOS. It works on the simulator because the simulator doesn't totally replicate the sandboxing environment on the actual hardware.

Rather than saving to the `resourcesPath` you should be saving your files to the `Documents` directory (or the cache directory, if appropriate).

You can get a path to the documents directory as follows:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

There's more information at this question here: [How to save file in resource folder of an app in Objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122912/how-to-save-file-in-resource-folder-of-an-app-in-objective-c)

Comment: Thanks.  After that, would loading the data back into the textfields be the same as what I was doing?

Comment: Yes, it should be - `arrayWithContentsOfFile` is how you'd normally populate from a plist. Just make sure you change your loading method to use the same Documents path as the saving one.